# Save PDF file shown by PDFKit middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit

If somebody is interested in saving the PDF file in the filesystem which is shown by PDFKit middleware gem, then here it is...

1. Override the `call` method of middleware.rb file.
2. In overriding just replace this line:

   ```
   body = PDFKit.new(translate_paths(body, env), @options).to_pdf
   ```

   with

   ```
   pdf = PDFKit.new(translate_paths(body, env), @options)
   file = pdf.to_file('Your/file/name/path')
   Mymodel.my_method()     #You can write your method here to use that file
   body = pdf.to_pdf   #Here you can change the response body
   ```

You can also override the response-body and content-type if you don't want to give pdf response. If you have any further query then go ahead.

This procedure is really help full because when you are having heavy JavaScript an CSS in your view file then `render_to_string` method will not work i.e. it will not render the heavy JavaScript.

Comment: I may have been better to post this in question form, then answer and accept your own question. This is now permanently listed as an unanswered question.

Comment: Just another fun reminder to please convert your edit into an answer :)

Comment: I have edited part of the question and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody is interested in saving the PDF file in the filesystem which is shown by PDFKit middleware gem, then here it is...

1. Override the `call` method of middleware.rb file.
2. In overriding just replace this line:

   ```
   body = PDFKit.new(translate_paths(body, env), @options).to_pdf
   ```

   with

   ```
   pdf = PDFKit.new(translate_paths(body, env), @options)
   file = pdf.to_file('Your/file/name/path')
   Mymodel.my_method()     #You can write your method here to use that file
   body = pdf.to_pdf   #Here you can change the response body
   ```

You can also override the response-body and content-type if you don't want to give pdf response. If you have any further query then go ahead.

This procedure is really help full because when you are having heavy JavaScript an CSS in your view file then `render_to_string` method will not work i.e. it will not render the heavy JavaScript.

Comment: This answer was provided by the asker himself. I am changing it into Q&A format