# Rails 3 + PDFKit: How to convert a view to PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdfkit

In my Rails 3 application **on Windows** I have the following page which shows a job receipt and lets user to edit it:

```
http://localhost:3001/jobs/45/invoice
```

I have also a "Create PDF" button in the bottom of the page. When pressed, `create_pdf_invoice` of my `JobsController` is called:

```
def create_pdf_invoice
    job = Job.find(params[:id])

    kit = PDFKit.new("<h1>Hello</h1><p>This is PDF!!!</p>", :page_size => "A4")
    file = kit.to_file("my_file_name.pdf")

    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end
end
```

All this works fine, i.e. the PDF is created!

My question is how can I print the invoice itself rather than this static text (like if I press "Print" on the `http://localhost:3001/jobs/45/invoice` page) ?

---

**UPDATE**

I tried to put

```
require 'pdfkit'
```

and

```
config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware
```

in `config/application.rb` as suggested [here](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit).

The server starts normally, but when I go to

```
http://localhost:3001/jobs/45/invoice.pdf
```

Ruby crashes:

[image]

I use:

```
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]
Rails 3.0.1
rake, version 0.8.7
pdfkit (0.5.0)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You want to convert the view for `http://localhost:3001/jobs/45/invoice` into a PDF or you want to `print` the current view with a (e.g. laser–) printer? Or print the PDF instead of the HTML?

Comment: I would like to convert `http://localhost:3001/jobs/45/invoice` to PDF.

Comment: after @tommasop's answer I don't have much to say :) but http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit, might also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to tell the application to use pdfkit as a middleware.

So somewhere in an initializer you need to put:

```
# PDFKit
require 'pdfkit'
middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware

PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = 'windows_path_to_wkhtmltopdf'
end
```

After this if you call

```
http://localhost:3001/jobs/45/invoice.pdf
```

a pdf should be generated for you.

PDFkit is a middleware that intercepts the pdf format rendering the page accordingly.

If you want you can also restrict pdfable routes in the config through regexes or string.

Just a caveat, if you have images in the page they must be called with an absolute path.

We are also finding some problems with pdfkit 0.5.0 but things are working fine with version 0.4.6 it is something to do with paths so maybe it can solve your issues.

Comment: My code example mentioned above works, i.e. `wkhtmltopdf` is configured correctly, so this is not the problem here...

Comment: I can give you two general hints: 1. you can try https://github.com/nkokkos/PDFKit this pdfkit version for windows xp machines 2. it seems a problem can be the non existence of the fork() function in windows http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/214311

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve the `fork()` issue in Windows ?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of PDFKit middle-ware you can only view the html page in pdf format in the browser.
If want to show the download prompt then you have to set the header in your action.

```
headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export"
```

Further, If you want to save the pdf file in server then you can try this link.

[Save PDF file shown by PDFKit middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154055/save-pdf-file-shown-by-pdfkit-middleware-solution)